# Bruteforce attack from 127.0.0.1?

Tags: hacked, heartbeat-api

I've got a very strange problem. Actually my server is being attacked by a brute force on wp-login.php. But when I look into the access log file I see that it's from 127.0.0.1...

```
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:01 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
www.*.fr:80 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2015:18:23:02 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6254 "-" "-"
```

I don't know what to do to stop that because by default fail2ban doesn't scan 127.0.0.1.

Do you have any idea ?

THanks !

Comment: This is the regular check for an active session from WordPress itself. Search for *heartbeat* on our site.

Comment: It may be that your site has a compromised file on the server which posts to the `wp-login.php` page attempting to get into the Admin Panel. Since your server is hosting the file its given the local IP. Do you have comments enabled on your website?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Comments are enabled on my website. I use Wordfence to protect and scan all the files but it doesn't detect anything now. 
When I restart Apache2 the infinite wp-login stops.